# Average Number of days between 2 dates in SQL Alchemy with Postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to get the difference in days of 2 dates, and average it. All examples seem to use date_sub that takes a date and and interval. Is there an function to get the difference of 2 dates, and then convert it into days, and average it.

from sqlalchemy.sql import func, text

Attempt line

```
func.avg(func.date_sub(Booking.departure_date, Booking.booking_date)).label('average_lead_time')).\
```

Query

```
query = db.session.query(func.avg(Booking.total_including_tax).label('average_fare'),
                        func.date_part('year', Booking.query_date).label("year"),
                        func.date_part('month', Booking.query_date).label("month"),
                        func.avg(func.date_sub(Booking.departure_date, Booking.booking_date)).label('average_lead_time')).\
                        filter(Booking.client_id == client_id).\
                        filter(Booking.customer_id == customer_id).\
                        filter(Booking.booking_type == 'Air').\
                        filter(Booking.query_date is not None).\
                        filter(Booking.query_date >= filter_date_range_min).\
                        filter(Booking.query_date < filter_date_range_max).\
                        group_by('year').group_by('month').\
                        order_by('year').order_by('month')
```

Comment: Where does `func` come from? Where are `date_sub`, `avg`, `date_part`, etc. defined?

Comment: `func` here is `sqlalchemy.sql.func`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line I was looking for was simply I didn't need the function as I can use the - sign. I needed the postgres justify_days function

```
func.avg(func.justify_days(Booking.departure_date - Booking.booking_date)).label('average_lead_time')).\
```

this helped

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html